# How to get gas fee to send erc20 token at mass volume?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I am learning node JS developing a crypto currency exchanger as a homework project where user can deposit ERC-20 token and Ethereum. I am generating unique ethereum deposit address for every user, where they can deposit ERC-20 token and ethereum. but after sometime I want to move the received ethereum and ERC-20 token to another address (cold wallet).

If someone only send ERC-20 token to the address and no etherum, then how I'll get ethereum to pay as gas fee to transfer the received ERC-20 token to cold wallet?

If suppose, I am first paying etherum (for gas fee) from cold address to the user address, and then using that etherum to transfer received ERC-20 token, will it work at mass level ? means if 10000 users do the same thing at the same time, will not it create a problem ? or is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no eth in that account, you can't take the ERC-20 token out.

Transfer some eth to the address and then get ERC-20 token out is the **only way**. The problem is how to save the gas as far as you can.

You can write a batch transfer contract to send eth to several hundred addresses in one go (the ceiling is determined by block gas limit), batch transfer saves gas. Then you can collect the ERC-20 tokens.

Of course, you can charge your user for compensation.